# java 8 neatbeans 8.0.2 swing component jTextfield

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I am working with Java 8 and NetBeans 8.0.2.

I can't insert a `private void jTextField1KeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt)` method by right clicking into the `jTextField`.

This is to complete a `okBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)` method. It is to allow user to put a data using the "return key" instead of "OK button".

Comment: what is the error message ?

Comment: First u should know with netbeans it is true that u cant insert `jTextField1KeyReleased` method by double clicking the text field. u have to right click the text field and go to **events->key->keyReleased** to add it.

Comment: And, don't use `KeyListener`s with text components, use a [`DocumentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#doclisteners) to monitor for changes to the text field or [a `DocumentFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) if you want to filter values going into the field

Comment: tanks for your quick answer !

Comment: tanks for your quick answer ! Yes to add the jTextFieldKeyReleased method i right click and choose event-->key--keyRealeased but after going back to the source code i see a lot of error message and i cannot delete i must escape the projet without saving it.I shall test your proposition with "documentListner"

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50453_01/doc.80/e50452/run_java_guis.htm#sthref418

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is to allow user to put a data using the "return key" instead of "OK button"

Then you can add an ActionListener to the text field. More specifically you can add the same ActionListener that you add to the OK button. Then the user can either click on the button or use the Enter key when focus is on the text field.

Comment: Yes exactly ! It's was so trivial !
Thank your answer is very good it's the simplest way to do that